# Prove that if f1(n) = O(g1(n)) and f2(n) = O(g2(n)), then f1(n) + f2(n) = O(g1(n) + g2(n)).

Tags: calculus, algorithms, asymptotics

I've been working on this problem for a quite a period of time and I don't even know where to start,I tried to follow the basic upper bound rule but it did not help me.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: HINT: if $f_1(n) \le C_1 g_1(n)$ and $f_2(n) \le C_2 g_2(n)$, then call $$C= \max (C_1, C_2)$$ so that $$f_1 + f_2 \le C(g_1 + g_2)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the @Crostul

Comment: When/if you choose non negative functions, then it will be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it because it's false. For example if $f_1(n)=f_2(n)=g_1(n)=1$ and $g_2=-1$ for all $n.$

The definition of the Landau Big-O is that $f(n)=O(g(n))$ as $n\to \infty$ means $\exists K\in \Bbb R^+\,\exists n_0\in\Bbb R\,(\,n\ge n_0\implies |f(n)|\le K|g(n)|\,).$

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation,Now I get it!

Comment: @Daniel How is $f_2(n) = 1 \in O(g_2(n) = -1)$? $k \ge $0, so$ -1 \cdot k$ will always be smaller than $f_2(n)$?

Comment: @WhatAMesh . Carefully note the absolute-value signs in the def'n of Big-O.